# Matlab Code to Convert Video to Sequence of Frames

Tags: matlab, frames

hi can someone tell me whats wrong with my Matlab Code to Convert Video to Sequence of Frames . it doesn't work.

```
clc
clear all
close all

file=aviinfo('test.avi');

frm_cnt=file.NumFrames

FileExtension='.bmp'

h = waitbar(0,'Please wait');

for i=1:frm_cnt

   % Read the Frame of the Video file
   frm(i)=VIDEOREADER ('test1.avi',i);
   % Convert Frame to image file   
   frm_name=frame2im(frm(i));
   %Create Filename to store
   Filename=strcat(strcat(num2str(i)),FileExtension);
   % Write image file  to the current folder
   imwrite(frm_name,Filename);

   waitbar(i/frm_cnt,h)

end
%Close Progress bar
close(h)
```

Comment: how come it does not work? Your computer is on fire? You get an error message? Plus you need to define only 1 `VideoReader` object

Comment: Sure you don't want to use FFMPEG?  Much better tool.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
    shuttleVideo = VideoReader('shuttle.avi');
    ii = 1;

    while hasFrame(shuttleVideo)
       img = readFrame(shuttleVideo);
       filename = [sprintf('%03d',ii) '.jpg'];
       fullname = fullfile(workingDir,'images',filename);
       imwrite(img,fullname)    % Write out to a JPEG file (img1.jpg, img2.jpg, etc.)
       ii = ii+1;
    end
```

Comment: Thank you very much sire.I'll try this :D